# Cloudinary: process.versions.node is undefined

Tags: node.js, webpack, cloudinary

My React action has a setup similar to https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/1501#issuecomment-289308498:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { GET_BOOKS, GET_BOOK, BOOKS_LOADING, BOOK_LOADING, DELETE_BOOK, GET_ERRORS } from './types';
import cloudinary from 'cloudinary';

cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: '**********',
    api_key: '***********',
    api_secret: '*********'
});
```

Once the `cloudinary` package was added webpack reported the missing `fs` module similar to the issue linked above. It was fixed with

```
node: {
  fs: 'empty'
},
```

in the `webpack.dev.config.js`.
Another issue resulted from it was `process.versions.node is undefined`. How do I fix it?

The complete repo is on https://github.com/ElAnonimo/booklister

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you installed “cloudinary” which is the node SDK, instead you should install “cloudinary-core” if you need just JS, or “cloudinary-react” if you need the React SDK.

--Yakir

Comment: Seems to be the answer. The Cloudinary React SDK has no means to create or delete an image and the link in the original question points to an example of the Node client use in the React component.